# Checking overflow for addc function

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

I am coding a C++ program to simulate a 16 bit virtual machine. I have a function 'addc' in which I have to check for overflow. I'm a little lost on the conditions for overflow. I know overflow happens when you add 2 positive numbers and you get a negative number, or when you add 2 negative numbers and you get a positive number. However, in my function addc, I have 3 numbers I have to add. Am I approaching this correctly?

My function is supposed to do this:

register destination = register destination + register source + carry bit

(rd = rd + rs + c)

So far for checking overflow, I have this code..

```
//Check when adding positive numbers gives negative result
//My carry bit is always positive (either 0 or 1)
if(rd >= 0 and rs >= 0 and c >= 0) and ((rd + rs + c) < 0)){
    //set overflow bit
}
else if( rd < 0 and rs < 0 and c < 0) and (rd + rs + c) > 0) ){
    //set overflow bit
}
```

My confusion is for the else if condition. C will always be 0 or 1, so it'll never go into the else if loop, so there's almost no reason to have the else if loop. Am I doing this right? Or would I have to add the carry bit (c) to one of the operands (either rd or rs) so I only have two operands to compare. Like this?

```
else if( rd < 0 and ((rs + c) < 0)) and (rd + (rs + c)) > 0) ){
    //set overflow bit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your second `if` statement seems to be operating under the impression that the carry bit could possibly be negative should be the first clue that something doesn't add up (as Foghorn Leghorn would say, "Hey, I think I just made a funny!").

The right way to do this is to simplify the case of a single add operation of three values into two separate add operations. First, add `rd` and `rs`, and check for overflow using the conditions you've already defined. Then, take the result of the first addition, and add it to the carry bit, and check for overflow here. The second overflow check can be very simple, given that the carry bit will be either 0, or 1.

The final result will set the overflow bit if either the first or the second add operation was determined to have overflowed.